# Laravel middleware for control user access to datas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, data-access-layer, laravel-middleware

I'm using this structure of user levels:

```
Company Owner
- Group Manager
-- Unit Manager
---Employee
```

I need to control users to access the datas in the database. Employee can access only that datas what he stored. The unit manager can access his own datas and datas of his emplyee too. Group manager can access to entire group's datas. And the company owner can acceess to everything.

I have some controllers like this:

```
class ClientController extends Controller
{
        public function index()
        {
            return Client::all();
        }
        // ...
}
```

What is the best practice in Laravel to control access to datas (not the controller) in some controllers, but not everywhere? Is here a good implementation for this issue?

Comment: use roles and permission concept.. if you mind to make yourself easier, here some good packages for you. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission and https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Great tips, but how can I tell this the user can see only that datas what he stored?

Comment: you can make `created_by` or `updated_by`  column in tables to indicate who is created the data.. then retrieved the data based on those column.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a middleware for each role, then in your web.php file, use route groups to assign access to the routes that the users can access. So for a route that both employee and unit manager can access, you pass the two middleware, for those that only group manager can access, you just pass group manager.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'group-manager','unit-manager']], 
function() {
  Route::get('client','ClientController@index'); 
});
```

Comment: Every user can access to the client controller. The different is what they can see there. How can I say "employee" can see only the datas what he stored?

Comment: For that case it’s just a query problem. If you store data, you should store a reference to the user who put it in. The ID of the user. When you are calling the data, you query the database for files where the ID of the person who put it is the same as the logged in users ID. So for every file storage, you have an input in your dB that would have a reference to the file. Or you use a unique file structure per user.

Comment: there aren't files, just datas in database. The user_id is stored to the records. Yes, this is a query problem :) The problem is: if I know the user_id, I can find his subordinates, but I want to find a way where I can find out what can see the user. If he is a sales employee, he can see only his records. If he is a unit manager, he can see his own datas, and all of his employees datas. But I have many controllers, and I don't want to duplicate this filter code. Is there any way to define it in one place, and use where I need it?

Comment: define it in the model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator go there as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Route. One good place for all middleware.

```
Route::get('/', function () {  ...  })->middleware('web');
```

Answer (score 0):

middleware is the right place for access control. For group middleware you can use by this format

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Company Owner']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@welcome');
    Route::get('/manage', ['middleware' => ['permission:manage-admins'], 'uses' => 'AdminController@manageAdmins']);
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Employee']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@welcome');
    Route::get('/manage', ['middleware' => ['permission:manage-admins'], 'uses' => 'AdminController@manageAdmins']);
});
```

For single route

```
Route::put('post/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->middleware('role:Employee');
```

You can use a package for user role base access control

> https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question wansn't clear enough, but I found a solution:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

use Auth;
use App\User;

class DataAccessScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        // find the actual user
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user = User::find( $user_id );

        // get all employees
        $employees = $user->allEmployeeFlatten();

        // get only the employee's ids
        $user_ids = $employees->pluck('id');

        // add current user's id too
        $user_ids->push( $user_id );

        // add the condition to every sql query
        $builder->whereIn('user_id', $user_ids);
    }
}
```

Here is the `User` model's `allEmployeeFaletten()` function:

```
public function allEmployeeFlatten() {
    $employees = new Collection();

    foreach ( $this->employee()->get() as $employee ) {
        $employees->push( $employee );

        // run only if the user is on a leader level
        if ( $employee->user_role_id != 5 ) {
            $employees = $employees->merge( $employee->allEmployeeFlatten() );
        }
    }

    return $employees;
}
```

This scope add a condition to all SQL queries every time I use the scope.